# smart table Angular

Tags: angular, smart-table, ng2-smart-table

I'm trying to use the [Akveo Smart Table](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/) for Angular

I bring data from my database in the table but I can't find documentation or videos about how to (Add , Update or delete) and sending the new data or deleting a row from my database.

Comment: Checkout [this](https://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/add-edit-delete-example-using-ng2-smart-angular-4-part-i/) , Very useful tutorial !

Comment: Thank you dude ! very good tutorial !